# Let $f(0,5)\to\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ be a continuous function such that $f(2)=\pi$, then $f(\pi)=\pi$. True/False?

Tags: calculus, functions

> Let $f(0,5)\to\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ be a continuous function such that $f(2)=\pi$, then $f(\pi)=\pi$. True/False?

The answer given is True.

I think we can prove this by taking a constant function as well. Is that correct?

Does the given domain and range have anything to do here?

Comment: Do you know the intermediate value theorem? Suppose $f(\pi) \neq \pi$, then think about the interval $[2,\pi]$ and what it's image would be under $f$. Of course you are predicting that it is constant, but that's not the only possibility till you argue it.

Comment: Note it says nowhere that the function is constant. Of course, if it *was* constant, then $f(\pi)=f(2)=\pi$, problem done. What remains is to *prove* that it is constant. Can you do it? (Hint: use Intermediate Value Theorem)

Comment: Thankyou for the comments. I am thinking about it. I'll respond in a while.

Comment: Responding with an answer will be the best , if you get the answer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I have posted my answer. Is that correct?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I have posted my answer. Is that correct?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Hi. I finally understood Intermediate Value Theorem and have posted my another answer. Thankyou for the guidance.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Hi. I finally understood Intermediate Value Theorem and have posted my another answer. Thankyou for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuous function maps connected sets to connected sets. Thus the image of $f$ must be a connected subset of $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. On the other hand, a subset of $X$ having at least two points is disconnected.

Let $S\subseteq X$, with $a,b\in S$ and $a<b$. Then take $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a<r<b$ and consider
$$
A=\{x\in S:x<r\},\qquad B=\{x\in S:x>r\}
$$
Can you prove that these sets show $S$ is disconnected?

Comment: I am trying to understand. Let $a=\pi, b=2\pi, r=5$. Set $A$ has elements which are less than $5$. Set $B$ has elements which are greater than $5$. So, $A$ and $B$ are disconnected. Not able to see their link with set $S$.

Comment: @aarbee You're looking in the wrong place: it's the codomain that's important. Let $S$ be the image of $f$; then the argument shows that if $S$ has more than two elements, then it is disconnected: contradiction. Therefore the image $S$ has at most one element (and is not empty).

Comment: ohkay, now I see your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the range is only irrational numbers, that means the output values would come after a jump (omitting rational numbers). But that would contradict the given statement that the function is continuous. It means the function is always giving the same value, in this case $\pi$. And this holds for the given interval $(0,5)$. Since $x=3.14...$ lies in this interval. So, $f(\pi)=\pi$.

Comment: I think that looks fine.  If you are in an analysis course for math major though, I would consider it unrigorous.

Comment: @Trebor Thanks for the comment. I'll make another attempt.

Comment: One issue:  If the domain of $f$ was, say, $(0,5) \cup (6,10)$, then the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} \pi & x\in (0,5)\\ \sqrt{2} & x\in (6,10)\}\end{cases}$ meets all the hypothesis, but is non-constant.  If your argument "rules out" such possibilities, then your argument is wrong.  Also, the fact that $\pi \in (0,5)$ is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Trebor Thanks for the feedback. I have posted my another answer.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks for the feedback. I have posted my another answer.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Input $\pi$ is relevant to the problem, isn't it? If the question was asking about $f(2\pi)$ then we couldn't have answered.

Comment: @aarbee:  Oops.  You're right: the fact that $\pi \in (0,5)$ is definitely relevant, I was thinking of the output being $\pi$ vs being any other constant.

Answer (score 0):

**Case I**: Let $f(x)$ be a constant function in the given interval. If $f(2)=\pi\implies f(\pi)=\pi$

**Case II**: Let $f(x)$ not be a constant function.

- A) Let $f(\pi)\gt f(2)$. And let $s$ be a number with $f(2)\lt s\lt f(\pi)$

Applying Intermediate Value Theorem on the interval $[2,\pi]$, we can get some $c\in(2,\pi)$ such that $f(c)=s$

Now whatever the value of $f(\pi)$ is, we can get infinite $s\in\mathbb Q\implies f(c)\in\mathbb Q$, which is a contradiction.

- B) Same holds for $f(\pi)\lt f(2)$

Hence, $f(x)$ can't be other than a constant function.

Comment: What about $f$ allows you to use the intermediate value theorem, and why wouldn't this work on my proposed counterexample on your other answer?

Comment: @JasonDeVito because the function won't be continuous that way?

Comment: My example in the other comment is continuous.  What hypothesis does the intermediate value theorem have? It's not just that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Image set is an interval, and that's not the case here?

Comment: That's the conclusion of the IVT, but what hypothesis excludes my example?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think you want me to see that we need continuity over a closed interval. So, even if we have a non-constant function like the one in your example, we can still prove $f(\pi) =\pi$ by taking a closed interval, say $[1,4]$. In both my answers, I have not covered this aspect.

Comment: I partly agree:  you need continuity over an interval, but the interval doesn't necessarily have to be closed.  But yes, "continuity over an interval" is the key I was hoping you to bring out to the front.